# sqlite3* to NSData

Tags: ios, sqlite, nsdata

Can a pointer to sqlite3 handler be converted to NSData?

I would then be able to encrypt and decrypt it.

I have:

```
sqlite *sqliteHandle;
NSData *dataDB = [NSData dataWithBytes:&sqliteHandle length:sizeof(sqliteHandle)];
```

But this only gives me the pointer, not the actual data.

Comment: The `sqllite *` is a pointer to the SQLLite connection object, it is not likely you can get data out of that directly. You need to execute a query first, then extract the data from the result.

Comment: And if the intent is to encrypt the database, that's the wrong way to do it.  SQLCipher is the only way to go.

Comment: Well. SQLCipher how does SQLCipher manage this? There must be some way.

Comment: SQLCipher manages it very well.  I'd suggest you not reinvent the wheel, especially since this one is a 4-cross with soldered spokes.

Comment: I have to. My customer does not allow the usage of any third party libraries. No matter wether open source or not.

Comment: I hope you're charging them a lot of money.

Comment: (Keeping in mind that SQLite itself is 3rd party open source that's been "borrowed" by Apple.)

Answer (score 0):

The sqllite * is a pointer to the SQLLite connection object, it is not likely you can get data out of that directly. You need to execute a query first, then extract the data from the result.

You probably want to call `sqlite3_column_blob` to get the raw data of a column.

Checkout the documentation; http://www.sqlite.org/capi3ref.html#sqlite3_column_blob

Comment: This is not what I need. I need to put the whole handler into an NSData object.

Comment: @user1423640 -- It's not something you can "put into an NSData object".  SQLite operates manages its own file in the file system, reading/writing records at a fairly low level.  You'd have to somehow intercept the I/O calls and map them into your imitation files system.  Maybe an interesting intellectual exercise, but kind of stupid from a business standpoint.

Comment: How about VFS to achieve this?

Comment: (Though I'm kind of curious whose VFS you're going to use.)

Comment: What do you mean whose VFS? Can you be more specific about this? Do you have any experience overwriting VFS functions?